# How to pass state variable into Html string

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native. Actually I want to create a PDF from HTML string, but I want to add data from the state variable.

something like this, but don't know the right way.

```
const htmlString = `
    <h1>Name: {this.state.name}</h1>
    <h2>Mobile number: {this.sate.mobileNumber}</h2>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" />
`;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use string  template literals notation: `${variable}`

```
const htmlString = `
<h1>Name: {this.state.name}</h1>
<h2>Mobile number: ${this.sate.mobileNumber}</h2>
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" />
`;
```

Comment: great. this is what i want.